# How can I check that a specific key in an array is empty at every index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So I have an array of objects to iterate over, on every iteration I need to check if a key named `blocks` has or has no length.

If all of the `blocks` keys are empty (length === 0) then I need to do an operation, otherwise do not. Get it? If ONNLY ONE `blocks` key has a `length > 0` then the operation should be avoided.

```js
    for (let i = 0; i < blockColumns.length; i++) {
      if (!blockColumns[i].blocks.length) {
        // TRIGGER OPERATION
      }
    }
```

In the code above the problem is that the operation will be trigger when at least one `blocks` key has no length, which what I don't need. The operation should be trigger ONLY when all of the `blocks` keys have `length === 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.every()` to check that every item has a 0 length (!0 === true). If all items have 0 length, the every would return `true`. If a `false` is encountered (ie length > 0), every would return `false` immediately.

```
const allEmpty = blockColumns.every(o => !o.blocks.length)

if(allEmpty) doSomething()
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something that [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) would be useful for:

```
if (blockColumns.every((el) => el?.blocks?.length === 0)) {
    // Do your operation
}
```

I've used [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) here since I'm not sure if there might be a case where an element doesn't have a `blocks` property, or if that property may not have a `length` property. But depending on how confident you can be in your data structure, you may not need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

well then you can do

```
x = 0
for (let i = 0; i < blockColumns.length; i++) {
      if (!blockColumns[i].blocks.length > 0) {
        x+=1;
      }
    }
   if(x == blockColumns.length){
     //do something
    }
```

this is a very simple way of doing it and i don't think that it's efficient at all but it gets the job done for now :D

Answer (score 0):

```
   let doOperation = true;
   for (let i = 0; i < blockColumns.length; i++) {
       if (blockColumns[i].blocks.length > 0) {
           doOperation = false
       }
   }
   if (doOperation) {
       //Some operation
   }
```

not sure if I follow but would this work?

Comment: This doesn't work. Remember that if ALL BLOCKS are empty, the operation should trigger.

Comment: @Reacting That's just what this code does? If any block is non-empty, `doOperation` becomes `false`.